# Matplotlib savefig image trim

Tags: python, matplotlib, savefig

The following sample code will produce a basic line plot with no axes and save it as an SVG file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.axis('off')
plt.plot([1,3,1,2,3])
plt.plot([3,1,1,2,1])
plt.savefig("out.svg", transparent = True)
```

How do I set the resolution / dimensions of the image? There is padding on all sides of the image beyond the line graph. How do I remove the padding so that the lines appear on the edge of the image?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I am continually amazed at how many ways there are to do the same thing in matplotlib.
As such, I am sure that someone can make this code much more terse.
At any rate, this should clearly demonstrate how to go about solving your problem.

```
>>> import pylab
>>> fig = pylab.figure()

>>> pylab.axis('off')
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
>>> pylab.plot([1,3,1,2,3])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x37d8cd0>]
>>> pylab.plot([3,1,1,2,1])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x37d8d10>]

>>> fig.get_size_inches()    # check default size (width, height)
array([ 8.,  6.])
>>> fig.set_size_inches(4,3) 
>>> fig.get_dpi()            # check default dpi (in inches)
80
>>> fig.set_dpi(40)

# using bbox_inches='tight' and pad_inches=0 
# I managed to remove most of the padding; 
# but a small amount still persists
>>> fig.savefig('out.svg', transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

[Documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) for `savefig()`.

Comment: is there a way to put these in matplotlibrc?  `Bad key "savefig.bbox_inches"`

Comment: You're most welcome. I do not know if it is possible to provide such configuration specifications using a matplotlibrc file.

Comment: One other command I like to use (in conjunction with those listed above) from pyplot is plt.tight_layout(), which removes excess white space around the figure.

Comment: And if I want to set as resolution in pixel for a png?

Comment: as for the style, see https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html: for "tight" use `savefig.bbox: tight`, for padding use `savefig.pad_inches: 0`.

Answer (score 3):

The default axis object leaves some room for titles, tick labels and the like. Make your own axis object that fills the whole area:

```
fig=figure()
ax=fig.add_axes((0,0,1,1))
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.plot([3,1,1,2,1])
ax.plot([1,3,1,2,3])
fig.savefig('out.svg')
```

In svg format I can't see the line that's right at the bottom, but in png format I can, so it's probably a feature of the svg renderer. You might want to add just a little padding to keep everything visible.

Comment: Correct. You can adjust the position of the axes in the figure by making the axes manually.  The pyplot (or pylab) command for making an axes includes this in its docstring: 

axes(rect, axisbg='w') where rect=[left, bottom, width, height] in normalized (0,1) units.  axisbg is the background color for the axis, default white

Answer (score 3):

A very easy way to trim down most padding is to call `tight_layout()` before saving the figure.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('plot.pdf')
```

Comment: plt.tight_layout() also did the job for me for SVGs. For PNGs, it wasn't necessary but somehow matplotlib seem to treat SVGs differently.